# WPF Set Visibility Through Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a list of Parent objects that contain Children.  Both Parents and Children have a Checked boolean property.  These object are bound to an ItemsControl that displays the hierarchy.

I also have a "Show checked" checkbox that is one of my application settings that will determine the Visibility of the Items in the ItemsControl.

So based of (Parent.Checked or Child.Checked) && Checkbox.Checked I need to bind the result to the items.

Thanks in advance,

B

Comment: Can you post some of your binding code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply BFree, I do not have any binding and after researching I think I am going to need to use the following class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

Still am unsure how best to go about binding to the result of two booleans.

Comment: easiest would be to create a new property that is the combination of the other properties, and bind to that property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply John but as one of the objects invloved is a collection I would have to create and maintain a copy of the collection with the new property unless I am missing something.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ItemsControl should bind its ItemsSource to a CollectionViewSource with a filter. That filter will filter out unchecked items if "Show checked" checkbox is checked otherwise it will accept all.

The filter will use a bool property on the Parent class to determine if the parent or its children are checked.